# Can't able to store data in the list

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout

I am retrieving data from the link in the code but I am not able to store it into a list and while running the app It shows only if block ...
I want to store JSON data into the users list.
When I put the print statement below for loop it shows only single data instead of whole once.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(Myapp());

class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

Future<List<userData>>_getUserData() async{
  final response =await http.get("https://dev.uneva.in/task_721/list.php");
  var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
  List<userData> users = [];
  for (var i in jsonData){
    userData user = userData(i["other"]["pid"], i["name"], i["description"],i["status"] ,i["tokenName"],i["updatedAt"] ,i["tokenNumber"]);
    users.add(user);
  }
  print(users.length);
  return users;
}


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ECHO-ALL"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getUserData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Waiting for data...."),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                    );
                  });
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class userData {
  final String pid;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final String status;
  final String tokenName;
  final String updatedAt;
  final String tokenNumber;

  userData(this.pid, this.name, this.description, this.status, this.tokenName,
      this.updatedAt, this.tokenNumber);
}
```

Where I am doing wrong ??

Comment: can you please paste your logs here, which you get from print statement?

Comment: I was using the wrong data types  now it is solved

Answer (score 1):

if you look into jsonData you could notice some fields NOT a Strings but int
you model class should be like this

```
class userData {
  final int pid;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final int status;
  final String tokenName;
  final String updatedAt;
  final int tokenNumber;

  userData(this.pid, this.name, this.description, this.status, this.tokenName, this.updatedAt, this.tokenNumber);
}
```

also will be much better if you rename this class by convention - UserData

Comment: Thanks bro and one more question I want to sort these according to their tokenNumber so how can I do that?

Comment: before return just sort it `users.sort((u1, u2) => u1.tokenNumber > u2.tokenNumber ? 1 : -1);`

Comment: Hey, there I want to count status and show them below app bar?