# Not showing value

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout

Passing pid as a parameter for getting particular data of user in URL to fetch data But I can't able to get data in the app but in console, its shows right 
What should I do??
Posting two images below one is output of the console and another one is  of the app

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class userPage extends StatefulWidget {
  int id;
  userPage({this.id});
  @override
  _userPageState createState() => _userPageState();
}

class _userPageState extends State<userPage> {
  String person_full_name;
  String person_gender;
  String person_age;
  String person_phone;
  String person_address;
  String person_pic;

  FetchData() async{
    var response = await http.get("https://dev.uneva.in/task_721/patient.php?id=${widget.id}");
    if(response.statusCode ==200){
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      print(data['person_full_name']);
      person_full_name = data['person_full_name'];
      person_gender = data['person_gender'];
      person_age = data['person_age'];
      person_phone = data['person_phone'];
      person_address = data['person_address'];
      person_pic = data['person_pic'];
    }
    else{
      print("Something went wrong");
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    FetchData();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('$person_full_name'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This is the result that I got in console]

[image: This is what I got in the App instead of showing name it show null]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only loading the data after going into the view, then you need to use a setState when setting the variables, so that it reflects on your view:

```
FetchData() async{
  var response = await http.get("https://dev.uneva.in/task_721/patient.php?id=${widget.id}");
  if(response.statusCode ==200){
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(data['person_full_name']);
    setState((){
      person_full_name = data['person_full_name'];
      person_gender = data['person_gender'];
      person_age = data['person_age'];
      person_phone = data['person_phone'];
      person_address = data['person_address'];
      person_pic = data['person_pic'];
    });
  }
  else{
    print("Something went wrong");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man! I have one more issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633727/cant-able-to-store-data-in-the-list in this I wants to count status which is one of the data of that api so how to do that.